# showInView: method for custom UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have created a custom `UIView` called `CustomMessage` that I am using throughout my program. The appearance of the `CustomMessage` is animated so I have written a method in the `CustomMessage` class called `showInView:` to show the view. For example, say that I wish to show the `CustomMessage` view in a particular view controller - I would use the following code:

```
CustomMessage *myCustomMessage = [[CustomMessage alloc] initWithMessage:@"Hello"];

[myCustomMessage showInView:self.view];
```

As you can see, this is quite similar to how a `UIActionSheet` is created and presented.

However, I am having problems with the memory management. If I put the following line of code directly following the two lines above:

```
[myCustomMessage release];
```

then (as expected) the program will crash with the `message sent to deallocated instance` error.

I am unsure what I need to do in my CustomMessage class so that I can release the object directly after calling the `showInView:` method so that I don't get a memory leak. Obviously this can be done, since that's how a `UIActionSheet` works (but I just can't get my head around how I can implement something similar - I can't figure out how the `CustomMessage` object can be retained by some other object, presumably the `self.view` (in the example above) which is displaying the `CustomMessage`, to avoid it releasing the object entirely while it is still in use).

Everything else works perfectly except for this little aspect, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd need to see your code for `showInView:` in `CustomMessage.m`. I would expect it to look something like the following.

```
- (void)showInView:(UIView *)view
{
    // pre-animation configuration
    [view addSubview:self];
    // do the animation
}
```

This means that the `CustomMessage` instance is retained by `view`. Also, if your implementation of `showInView` uses concurrency at all it is possible it is returning immediately allowing `MyCustomMessage` to be released and then background operations are trying to access the release object. I'm just guessing w/o seeing your code.

What is the crash log? What message is sent to what object in what context? This info will localize the problem.

If none of the above helps you solve the problem, post your code for `showInView` as well as details from the crash log and I'll take another look.

Comment: Is this method a good MVC pattern design? The view is controlling itself, which would violate the MVC patter. Am I wrong? Just trying to understand. Thanks